Animating scale on an object while grabbed in VR glitching position
I'm using the hand-tracking-grab-controls component in a-frame to enable hand tracking and grabbing. While I have an object grabbed, I want to be able to animate its scale when I press a button - basically, grab something and enlarge what you've grabbed.
However, when I do that it does scale as expected, but it glitches back to the object's point of origin during the animation. I'd like to prevent that from happening.
I've tried animating it manually by ticking increases in size directly to the object3D, but it does the same thing, except smoother.  I feel like it might have something to do with the way hand-tracking-grab-controls reparents the grabbed object - some confusion between world space and local space, but I have no idea why that would cause this. Perhaps it's something like the object is somehow becoming "ungrabbed" during the animation?
This is the animation code, but there is nothing really special about it:
entity.setAttribute('animation__sizemax', {
        property: 'scale',
        to: `${maxscale}`,
        dur: 500,
        easing: 'easeInOutElastic',
        loop: false,
      });

It does this whether I fire the command from an emit from a button, or even from a shake gesture I was playing with.

It might have to do with how the grab function applies a matrix4 to it... but I haven't figured out a solution yet. I'm having a hard time trying to adjust the matrix4 value directly to adjust.
